# Hide preference for results in English senetence from search results page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

I want to hide the sentence `"preference for results in English"` in my enterprise search center site page. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Edit the Search Results Web part.
2. Uncheck the settings for Show language dropdown under Result Control settings
3. Click Apply and Ok.
4. Check in the changes and Publish the page.
   check the below image [image]

Comment: its done. one more doubt, how to  format the date , thats given in callouts in the search results ? i dotn wannna  show the default date format, mm/dd/yyy, instead i need to get the date format in dd-mmm-yyyy  ie, 23-march-2017 format

Comment: Do you want for date format for the Refinements..? if yes ,while choosing the  Refinements you can format the date.

Comment: no, in the callouts, we are seeing the date format . this date format needs to be changed , for a every search results. its coming under the CALLOUTS framework, if you know how to modify the same, ...